# What is the maximum resolution supported by elementary OS?

Tags: display, hardware

I recall reading somewhere either here or on the elementary OS site that the maximum resolution supported is something like 2560x1600.  Is that true, or are higher resolutions supported?

I ask because I've got two monitors, one 2560x1600 and the other 3840×2160.  Elementary OS looks great and I'd like to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack!  It was a dumb question.  It supports pretty much the same resolutions as other distributions.  I managed to install and it's running just fine.

I was thrown off by a blog post I read earlier about HiDPI screens and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll be disappointed. I have annLG 29” Ultra-Wide, recommended resolution is 2560x1080. Nax res on all Linux I’ve tried it 1920x1080.. done all the CVT, xrandr, add mode crap and won’t take.. waste of time..